# listen returns without waiting for a connection

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

When I run my program I get output

```
Listening on port 65004
listen -> 0
```

Why does `listen` returns without waiting for a connection?

```
#define PORT 65004

bool listen_on_port(int port)
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);
    if (error)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)             //Wrong Winsock version?
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    // Open a socket.
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    // Bind the socket to the port it will be listening on.
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == bind(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&addr, sizeof(addr)))
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "Listening on port " << port << '\n';
    auto r = listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);
    std::cout << "listen -> " << r << '\n';
    if (r == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero means that the call succeeded. However, I believe that the problem is a misunderstanding in what `listen` does. The [Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) has a good explanation, but it works the same way with winsock:

> listen() marks the socket referred to by sockfd as a passive socket,
> that is, as a socket that will be used to accept incoming connection
> requests using accept(2).

It is `accept` that waits for an incoming connection and returns a new socket, that you can use to communicate with the client. See [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> The accept() system call is used with connection-based socket types
> (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET).  It extracts the first connection
> request on the queue of pending connections for the listening socket,
> sockfd, creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file
> descriptor referring to that socket.  The newly created socket is not
> in the listening state.  The original socket sockfd is unaffected by
> this call.

I can also recommend [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html//index.html)

Edit: Added links to the winsock API pages:
[listen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen), [accept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept) (I still think the Linux man page has a better, to the point explanation of what `listen` does)

Comment: The code in the question is for Windows (hence the `windows` tag and use of Winsock). Whilst the details are similar, Windows-specific references rather than links to Linux man-pages would be more relevant.

Comment: @Iridium Fair point, I added some winsock links to the answer.